# How can I make a Progress Bar have negative progress on Android Studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, progress-bar

I am developing a Compass app, and I need a circle Progress Bar, this circle is used to fill the space between the North and the current orientation of the device.

Progress Bar works fine when it has to go from 0 progress (North) to 50 progress (south), but the problem is that I can not make the Progress Bar fill from the left, I tried to duplicate it and set a negative scale, but nothing.

Anybody knows a way to set a negative progress to the Progress Bar, or make it start filling from the left?

This is the progress bar XML code:

```
      <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressDegrees"
        android:layout_width="335dp"
        android:layout_height="335dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:progress="5"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"/>
```

This is how the progress bar looks like with "5" of progress, but when I insert a negative value, it dissapears, instead of going left.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZbzu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code

```
    android:scaleX="-1"
```

This will flip your view in X axis. For flipping view in Y axis, you can use this code

```
    android:scaleY="-1"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with scale X, and negative rotation.

Comment: Sure, please give an upvote & check so it will help others in finding the solution